# MySQL how to use current time if value of timestamp field is explicitly null?

Tags: mysql

I want to accomplish the following:

I field in a table in MySQL that, when provided with a NULL value, should resolve to the current time.

I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    bar TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    baz INT
);

-- Now let's insert something.
INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (null, 2);

-- Now let's make sure it works as desired.
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected:

```
**********
bar  | baz
**********
null | 2
```

It only works when I leave off the column's value in an `INSERT` statement.

How can I make the above `INSERT` statement work? That is, the field should be set to the default time when the value is null.

Comment: What you're asking isn't possible using only declarative features in SQL: a `DEFAULT` constraint is only used when the column is omited from an `INSERT` (or use `DEFAULT` for the value) - so in order to replace or override values in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` you'll need to use a `TRIGGER` (which is non-declarative and introduces problems of its own). Instead, why not make `bar` a `NOT NULL` column and ensure all `INSERT` statements omit that column? Or use the `DEFAULT` keyword (if MySQL supports it, I'm unsure) as: `INSERT INTO foo ( bar, baz ) VALUES ( DEFAULT, 123 )`

Comment: @Dai You should post an answer if that's your answer. If you only post a comment, the question remains "unanswered" forever, and anyone who tries to post an answer will be accused of just copying your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking isn't possible using only declarative features in SQL: a `DEFAULT` constraint is only used when the column is omited from an `INSERT` (or uses `DEFAULT` for the value) - otherwise the only other way (that I'm aware-of) to replace or override values in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` requires using a `TRIGGER` (which is non-declarative and introduces problems of its own).

Instead, why not make `bar` a `NOT NULL` column and ensure all `INSERT` statements omit that column? Or change your `INSERT` statements to use the `DEFAULT` keyword?

Like so:

```
INSERT INTO foo ( bar, baz )
VALUES ( DEFAULT, 123 )
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `DEFAULT` keyword in insertion.